# Did the 'make Europe great again' alliance turn into an official EP party or group?

Tags: european-parliament, italy, poland, hungary

On April 1st (but seemingly not a joke) [from Euronews](https://www.euronews.com/2021/04/01/orban-salvini-and-morawiecki-form-new-right-wing-european-alliance)...

> Hungary's Viktor Orbán has joined forces with Polish Prime Minister Mateusz Morawiecki and Italy's Matteo Salvini to form a new right-wing political alliance at European level. [...]
>
> Prior to the encounter in Budapest, Salvini had said the goal of the alliance was to "make Europe great again, returning to its original values".

I can't find much else on what happened since then, either searching for the "MEGA" slogan or even for the three leaders' names together. So, did they further formalize the alliance in some way, e.g. as an EP [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_groups_of_the_European_Parliament) or even party?

Comment: Salvini is essentially a buffoon - all bark and no bite. Right now his main preoccupation is in internal politics, he's afraid to lose the far right electors to Fratelli d'Italia and at the same time he's risking to lose the leadership of his party to the more moderated Giorgetti. I'm not even sure he even remembers about a provocation he did six months ago.